# VB script to compare folder size from its previous size stored in a text file

Tags: vbscript

I need to develop a script which compares the size of a folder from its previous size which is saved in text file. If the folder size has increased it should prompt folder size increased.

Answer (score 1):

**Monitoring directory with VBScript**

```
Option Explicit
Dim fso,Message,Message2,Msg,intInterval,strDrive,strFolder,strComputer,objWMIService,strQuery
Dim colEvents,objEvent,objTargetInst,objPrevInst,objProperty,ws,LOG_FILE_PATH,LogFile,Chemin,MonTableau
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ws = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strComputer = "." 
Chemin = Parcourir_Dossier()
MonTableau = Split(Chemin,"\")
LogFile = MonTableau(UBound(MonTableau)) & ".log"
LOG_FILE_Path = ws.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%AppData%") & "\" & LogFile
intInterval = "2"
'****************************************************************************************************
Function Parcourir_Dossier()
    Dim ws,objFolder,Copyright
    Copyright = "[ © Hackoo © 2014 ]"
    Set ws = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set objFolder = ws.BrowseForFolder(0,"Choose the folder to watch for "_
    & Copyright,1,"c:\Programs")
    If objFolder Is Nothing Then
        Wscript.Quit
    End If
    Parcourir_Dossier = objFolder.self.path
end Function
'****************************************************************************************************
Chemin = Split(fso.GetAbsolutePathName(Chemin),":")
strDrive  = Chemin(0) & ":"
strFolder = Replace(Chemin(1), "\", "\\")
If Right(strFolder, 2) <> "\\" Then strFolder = strFolder & "\\"
'Connexion au WMI
Set objWMIService = GetObject( "winmgmts:" &_ 
"{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" &_ 
strComputer & "\root\cimv2" )
'La chaîne de la requête
strQuery =  _
"Select * From __InstanceOperationEvent" _
& " Within " & intInterval _
& " Where Targetinstance Isa 'CIM_DataFile'" _
& " And TargetInstance.Drive='" & strDrive & "'"_
& " And TargetInstance.path='" & strFolder & "'"
'Exécutez la requête
Set colEvents = _
objWMIService.ExecNotificationQuery(strQuery)  
Do 
    Set objEvent = colEvents.NextEvent()
    Set objTargetInst = objEvent.TargetInstance
    Select Case objEvent.path_.Class 
'Si c'est le cas de la création de fichier ou d'un événement de suppression et afficher
'juste le nom du fichier
    Case "__InstanceCreationEvent" 
        Message = DblQuote(objTargetInst.Name) & " is created !"
        Message2 = String(10,"*") & Now & String(10,"*") & vbCrLf & Message & vbCrLf & String(70,"*")
        Call Log(LOG_FILE_Path,Message2)
        MsgBox Message,VbInformation,Message
    Case "__InstanceDeletionEvent" 
        Message = DblQuote(objTargetInst.Name) & " is deleted !"
        Message2 = String(10,"*") & Now & String(10,"*") & vbCrLf & Message & vbCrLf & String(70,"*")
        Call Log(LOG_FILE_Path,Message2)
        MsgBox Message,VbInformation,Message
'Si c'est le cas de la modification du fichier,comparer les valeurs de propriété de la cible et de l'instance précédente
'et afficher les propriétés qui ont été changé comme la taille et LastModified
    Case "__InstanceModificationEvent" 
        Set objPrevInst = objEvent.PreviousInstance
        For Each objProperty In objTargetInst.Properties_
            If objProperty.Value <> _
            objPrevInst.Properties_(objProperty.Name) Then
            Message = "modified file :        " & vbCrLf &_
            objTargetInst.Name & vbCrLf &_
            "Property :       "_
            & objProperty.Name & vbCrLf &_
            "Last Value : "_
            & objPrevInst.Properties_(objProperty.Name) & vbCrLf &_
            "New value :      " _
            & objProperty.Value
            Message2 = String(10,"*") & Now & String(10,"*") & vbCrLf & Message & vbCrLf & String(70,"*")
            Call Log(LOG_FILE_Path,Message2)
            MsgBox Message,64,DblQuote(objTargetInst.Name)
        End If    
    Next
End Select 
Loop
'**********************************************************************************************
Function DblQuote(Str)
DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'**********************************************************************************************
Sub Log(strLogFileChemin,strLogContent)
Const APPEND = 8
Dim objFso,objLogFile
Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If Not objFso.FileExists(strLogFileChemin) Then objFso.CreateTextFile(strLogFileChemin, True).Close
Set objLogFile = objFso.OpenTextFile(strLogFileChemin,APPEND)
objLogFile.WriteLine strLogContent
objLogFile.Close
End Sub 
'**********************************************************************************************
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this :

```
Folder = "c:\your\path\tata"
File = "c:\your\file\containing\the\value.txt"
set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set fileRead = objfso.OpenTextFile(file, 1) 
content = fileRead.Readline
FileRead.close
set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(Folder)
if objFolder.Size > Clng(content) Then  Wscript.Echo "The Folder size [" & ObjFolder.size & "] is bigger then [" & content & "]"
```

If you need to update the value in your text file.

```
Folder = "c:\your\path\tata"
File = "c:\your\file\containing\the\value.txt"
set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set fileRead = objfso.OpenTextFile(file, 1)
content = fileRead.Readline
FileRead.close
set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(Folder)
set fileWrite = objfso.OpenTextFile(file, 2)
FileWrite.writeline(ObjFolder.size)
FileWrite.close
if objFolder.Size > Clng(content) Then  Wscript.Echo "The Folder size [" & ObjFolder.size & "] is bigger then [" & content & "]"
```